# CSS sub-div positioning

Tags: html, css

I am preparing for my upcoming HTML exams and practicing CSS right now. I come across a problem where my sub-div won't stay inside my main-div. What I want is to have the 3 sub-blocks fill up all the spaces within the big block evenly. If any of you can help that'd be greatly appreciated!!
Here are the code.

HTML:

```
    <div id="blk1">
    <div id="sb1">
        <p id="htitle">Hotel 1</p>
        <img id="hpic" src="hpic1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="sb2">
        <p id="htitle">Hotel 2</p>
        <img id="hpic" src="hpic2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="sb3">
        <p id="htitle">Hotel 3</p>
        <img id="hpic" src="hpic3.jpg">
    </div>
    </div><!-- End of Blk1 -->
```

CSS:

```
#blk1{
border: 1px solid blue;
position:relative;
}

#sb1{
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
position:relative;
width:33%;
}

#sb2{
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
width:33%;
}

#sb3{
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
width:33%;
}
```

Comment: because of float left

Comment: @winresh24 but if I don't float them, they will stack up vertically instead of horizontally within the mainblk

Comment: try to search for the clearfix and add it to your parent div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are duplicating CSS code, I suggest to use class instead. Then use `box-sizing: border-box;` property to take border in consideration of the calcul of the `width` :

```
.sb{
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  width:33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then, `id` of an element should be **unique**, so you have to use this id `#htitle` only one time, same for `#hpic` or use a class instead.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a7bq9o1/2/)